# The Interval until Android Wear app restart

Tags: android, alarmmanager, wear-os, android-pendingintent

I've developed an android wear app.
In this app, I want to be relaunched it after
the `onStop()` is called and close it.

So I added the following codes in the `onStop()`.

```
Intent intent = new Intent(getIntent());
AlarmManager amgr = (AlarmManager)getSystemService(Context.ALARM_SERVICE);
amgr.set(AlarmManager.RTC_WAKEUP, System.currentTimeMillis() + 500, PendingIntent.getActivity(WatchActivity.this, 0, intent, 0));
android.os.Process.killProcess(Process.myPid());
```

These codes are succeeded to relaunch itself.
However, it takes about 5sec until my app starts again.

I want to restart within 1sec when the `onStop()` is called.

Are there any solution?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Starting from API 19, alarm delivery is inexact (see [docs](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/AlarmManager.html)). Outside of that, why do you want to restart your app if it is stopped? That doesn't sound right ....

Comment: Thanks for your reply.
Actually, I want to disable the Android Wear's palm close but I cannot find the solution. So I try to implement the restart process after palm closing.

Comment: Please don't do anything of that sort; you are trying a flow that is against what the framework is doing and that is not good for your users at all. I don't know the nature of your app but you may want to look into the Ambient Mode (https://developer.android.com/training/wearables/apps/always-on.html)  that has been added to the framework.